# Mounting shared memory in XCP/ XEN Server,for storing VM

Tags: linux, virtualization, xen, cloud, memory

**Requirement**

- vm with 2HDD each 1gb
- OS will be installed on hdd 1 and required data on HDD 2

I want all my VM running on Xen Cloud Platform XCP 1.1 to use **/dev/shm** of host machine for HDD1.

Is there a way to do that using citrix xen centre 6.(I have done it using xen and virt-manger.)

i have mounted /dev/shm to a mount pont /RAM and i want all vms  to be moved to this partition and run from there.(in case of xen i moved each **.img** file to /RAM and started vm from there.).
in case of XCP how can i make the VM run on /dev/shm

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Seems like a strange thing to do.

Comment: i have only a sinlge hdd.. and need to run 7 vms sharing a single hard disk,among sing VM is adding too much disk i/o.So is there a way to make it work using xen centre.It is possible with xen and virt-manger.but virt-manger can not offer every feature that of xen centre.